# Access parameters from Rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails form that includes a script to generate a Stripe payment form. Nested within the form is a `fields_for` tag. Here is my whole charges/new.html.erb file:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>  


      <div class="col-md-8">

      <h3>Confirm address and make payment</h3>
      <br>  

      <%= form_tag charges_path do %>

         <%= fields_for :charges do |f| %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, size: 20, :value => current_user.first_name, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, size: 20, :value => current_user.last_name, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :address %>
            <%= f.text_area :address, size: 40, :value => current_user.address, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :city %>
            <%= f.text_field :city, size: 20, :value => current_user.city, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>  

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :state %>
            <%= f.text_field :state, size: 2, :value => current_user.state, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>  

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email, size: 40, :value => current_user.email, :class => 'form-control' %>
          </div>

          <%= f.hidden_field :total_price, :value => @cart.total_price  %>

          <% end %>

        <br>

          <article>
              <% if flash[:error].present? %>
                <div id="error_explanation">
                  <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
                </div>
              <% end %>
              <label class="amount">
                <span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price * 7.35) %></span>
              </label>
          </article>

          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                  data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
                  data-description="A one-time payment"
                  data-amount="<%= @cart.total_price * 735 %>"
                  data-locale="auto"></script>
        <% end %>



      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2"></div>  



    </div>
```

And here is my Charges Controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentCart
    before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
    #before_action :set_charge, only: [:create]

    def new
        #@charge = Charge.new
    end

    def create #METHOD IS CALLED AFTER PAYMENT IS MADE
    # Amount in cents

    @charge = Charge.new(charge_params)
    @amount = (@cart.total_price * 735) 


    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Witch or Wizard',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) 

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_charge
      @charge = Charge.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def charge_params
      params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :email, :total_price)
    end

end
```

When I submit this form, I get this error pertaining to my set_charge method:

> Couldn't find Charge with 'id'=

What am I doing wrong here? The Stripe functionality works fine, but I am trying to save the customer information contained in the forms to the database as well.

Here is my log when I submit the form:

```
    Started POST "/charges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-16 20:45:24 -0400
Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Kj986IJXX+NQuJ3msJelyYSYQfmQa+i+kmqdseoidR11mmt2T6xZrXi/WtgjAb2u6zs4GRF9nIr6/ZW3U4F/g==", "charges"=>{"first_name"=>"Matt", "last_name"=>"Cole", "address"=>"1 South Main St", "city"=>"Marietta", "state"=>"GA", "email"=>"mattaecole@gmail.com", "total_price"=>"4"}, "stripeToken"=>"tok_1AgNMTJG64O6iQtfUhLFVKZF", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"mattaecole@gmail.com"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 71], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  LineItem Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 71]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 71], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 71]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = ?  [["id", 135]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  DELETE FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ?  [["id", 71]]
   (1.7ms)  commit transaction
  Rendering charges/create.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered charges/create.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 1529ms (Views: 61.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that no `id` is sent after submitting the form, thus the error.

But, you don't need that method at all, since your are creating the `Charge` and its `id` has not been created yet. And, further on, you replace `@charge` (which is set in `set_charge`) in the first line of your `create` action, that is:

```
@charge = Charge.new(charge_params)
```

To fix the error just **delete** the following line from your controller and you should be fine:

```
before_action :set_charge, only: [:create]
```

---

In general, you will want to use such callbacks (i.e. for finding an existing record) only when updating a record, that is, only  with `edit` and `update` actions.

So, if you plan to add such actions to your controller, change the above line (instead of deleting it) to be executed only for `edit` and `update` actions:

```
before_action :set_charge, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it though, and now I'm getting an error with my charge_params method:

param is missing or the value is empty: charge

Comment: @matt Since you are using `form_tag` the sent attributes are not being grouped under `charge` key, but your strong params method (i.e. `charge_params`) requires it. So try removing `require`, leaving that line like this: `params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :email, :total_price)`.

Comment: When I try removing require, the form is submitted without any errors appearing, but nothing is added to the charges table.

Comment: @matt Can you share your log? The part where is shows the parameters being sent.

Comment: Yes, I just added the log to the end of my initial post.

Comment: @matt Ohh, i see now, i missed the `fields_for` in your view. So add `require` again but use `charges` instead of `charge`, like this: `params.require(:charges).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :email, :total_price)`.

Comment: OK, I started using require with :charges. I am no longer seeing any mention of unpermitted parameters in the log but it is still not adding anything to the charges table. I updated my post to show this new log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149342/discussion-between-gerry-and-matt).